# Pandas - how to return indices in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe reads an excel sheet. I want to find the 5 largest values in a particular column. 
So I can use:

```
five_largest = df.nlargest(5, 'ColumnName')
```

However, instead of printing the entire 5 rows, I would like to know the indices of the 5 largest, so I can only print the columns that I prefer from that row.

Can anyone help?

Comment: You can try df.nlargest(5, 'ColumnName').index

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `index`:

```
df.nlargest(5, 'ColumnName').index
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you